# Почему numpy.median не всегда правильно считает медиану?

Tags: numpy, статистика

Всем привет

```
def get_smooth(values, window, name_op):

l1 = []  

for i in range(10):

    # Нахождение медианы
    if name_op == 'median':
        np1 = np.around(values[i:i+window],2)
        m = np.median(np1)
        l1.append(round(m,2))
        print(f'Row: {np1}; Median: {m}')
    
    # Нахождение среднего
    if name_op == 'mean':
        np1 = np.around(values[i:i+window],2)
        m = np.mean(np1)
        l1.append(round(m,2))
        print(f'Row: {np1}; Mean: {m}')
    
print('------------------------------------')
```

[image: Вывод функции]

Как видно на простых значениях медиана как полагается равна среднему значению ряда, а на реальных данных почему-то не так.

При этом среднее считается нормально:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

С чем это может быть связано?

Comment: В ваших примерах массивы не упорядочены.

Comment: * Хочу добавить, что такая же проблема подсчета медианы и в случае ряда из четного количества элементов, где она должна считаться как среднее между двумя центральными элементами.

Comment: Медиана чётного числа элементов - любое число из промежутка межлу двумя "средними".

Comment: Я пока не увидел примера где медиана вычислена неправильно.

Comment: Я понял свой косяк
Ключевое слово "упорядоченного"
Мне казалось, что просто центровой элемент берется
Мой косяк
Спасибо

Comment: Весь смысл медианы именно в упорядоченности.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy а разве не среднее арифметическое, если центральных элемента два?

Comment: `Медиана чётного числа элементов - любое число из промежутка межлу двумя "средними"` - никогда не сталкивался с таким определением медианы ;)

Comment: @CrazyElf определение с индексами не очень математично. Медиану можно определить как число `x` такое что `sum(abs(x - a_i)) -> min`. Это определение не требует порядка и совпадает с традиционным определением медианы. В смысле этого определения годится "любое число между двумя средними". Но это уже терминология. https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0_(%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0)#%D0%9D%D0%B5%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C_%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy Чисто по логике ваше определение вполне нормальное, но в английской Вики я такого не нашёл, хотя может плохо искал. Там сразу нормальное определение написано, привычное. И в статистике тоже берут среднее. Поэтому я как-то удивился, да и MaxU тоже удивился.